# how to print textbox value in asp.net using javascript

Tags: asp.net

I am facing in retrieving value of textbox while printing appropriate section.

```
    function PrintPanel() {

     var panel = document.getElementById("<%=pnlContents.ClientID %>");
     var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');


     printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');

     printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
     printWindow.document.write(panel.innerHTML);
     var text = document.getElementById('<%=Textbook.ClientID%>').value;
     printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        printWindow.document.close();
        setTimeout(function () {

            printWindow.print();
        }, 500);
        return false;
      }
```

Comment: You haven' used "text" variable in printing.

Comment: can you show me in code please what you are trying to say.

Comment: when i use text variable then it works in second time.